# Page Transitions

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem with transitions at the moment using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfPageTransitions.aspx

The problem is that if I have a button on `UserControl1` and when the button is pressed, it triggers `UserControl2` to transition, but when this happens, the background of `UserControl2` is visible but the other things like text and buttons are merged together with `UserControl1`.

How can I either apply a transition to `UserControl1` so that only `UserControl2` is shown?

Modified code:

NewPage.xml

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Test test = new Test();
    pageTransitionControl.SetPreviousUserControl(newPage);
    pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(test);
}
```

PageTransition.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PageTransition : UserControl
{
    private UserControl currentUserControl;
    private UserControl previousUserControl;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TransitionTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TransitionType",
        typeof(PageTransitionType),
        typeof(PageTransition), new PropertyMetadata(PageTransitionType.SlideAndFade));

    public PageTransitionType TransitionType
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageTransitionType)GetValue(TransitionTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TransitionTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public PageTransition()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowPage(UserControl newPage)
    {
        currentUserControl = newPage;

        if (contentPresenter.Content != null)
        {
            UserControl oldPage = contentPresenter.Content as UserControl;
            oldPage.Loaded -= newPage_Loaded;
            UnloadPage(oldPage);
        }
        else
        {
            ShowNextPage();
        }
    }

    void ShowNextPage()
    {            
        currentUserControl.Loaded += newPage_Loaded;

        contentPresenter.Content = currentUserControl;

        if (currentUserControl != null)
        {
            currentUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Panel.SetZIndex(currentUserControl, 100);
        }

        if (previousUserControl != null)
        {
            previousUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Panel.SetZIndex(previousUserControl, 0);      
        }
    }

    void UnloadPage(UserControl page)
    {
        Storyboard hidePage = (Resources[string.Format("{0}Out", TransitionType.ToString())] as Storyboard).Clone();

        hidePage.Completed += hidePage_Completed;

        hidePage.Begin(contentPresenter);
    }

    void newPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard showNewPage = Resources[string.Format("{0}In", TransitionType.ToString())] as Storyboard;

        showNewPage.Begin(contentPresenter);

        currentUserControl = sender as UserControl;
    }

    void hidePage_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contentPresenter.Content = null;

        ShowNextPage();
    }

    public void SetPreviousUserControl(UserControl userControl)
    {
        previousUserControl = userControl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have anymore questions feel free to ask. If not you should mark this as an answer.

Comment: I figured the ordering of the UserControls, the pageTransitions element in the XAML has to be after all the content of that XAML.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this do the following:

1. Keep a Global reference to the Current and Previous UserControls
2. Get your transition as normal but ad a completed event to the DoubleAnimation
3. Make the Current UserControl Visible and set the ZIndex higher than the Previous UserControl
4. Make the Previous UserControl Visivle ans set the ZIndex lover than the Current UserControl
5. Start the animation
6. Set the Visual Brush to the Previous UserControl
7. Remove the effect from the Current UserControl
8. Now when the animations finished
9. Set the ZIndex of the Current UserControl to what you set the Previous UserControl
10. Set the Previous UserControl to Visible
11. Set the Previous UserControl to the Current UserControl

This is **MY** modified version of this transition library so you may have to tweak it to your needs

#### Globals

```
    private UserControl CurrentUserControl;
    private UserControl PreviousUserControl;
    private Random Random;
```

#### Methods

```
    private void TransitionEffectStarting(UserControl userControl)
    {
        CurrentUserControl = userControl;

        TransitionEffect[] effectGroup = Global.TransitionEffects[Random.Next(Global.TransitionEffects.Length)];
        TransitionEffect effect = effectGroup[Random.Next(effectGroup.Length)];

        RandomizedTransitionEffect randomEffect = effect as RandomizedTransitionEffect;
        if (randomEffect != null)
            randomEffect.RandomSeed = Random.NextDouble();

        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
        animation.AccelerationRatio = 0.5;
        animation.DecelerationRatio = 0.5;
        animation.Completed += TransitionEffectCompleted;

        if (CurrentUserControl != null)
        {
            CurrentUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Panel.SetZIndex(CurrentUserControl, 1);
        }

        if (PreviousUserControl != null)
        {
            PreviousUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Panel.SetZIndex(PreviousUserControl, 0);
        }

        else
            Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        effect.BeginAnimation(TransitionEffect.ProgressProperty, animation);

        if (PreviousUserControl != null)
        {
            VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(PreviousUserControl);
            visualBrush.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 0, PreviousUserControl.ActualWidth, PreviousUserControl.ActualHeight);
            visualBrush.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
            effect.OldImage = visualBrush;
        }

        if (CurrentUserControl != null)
            CurrentUserControl.Effect = effect;
    }

    private void TransitionEffectCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentUserControl != null)
        {
            Panel.SetZIndex(CurrentUserControl, 0);
            CurrentUserControl.Effect = null;

            if (PreviousUserControl != null)
                PreviousUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        PreviousUserControl = CurrentUserControl;
    }
```

Hope this helps you out. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks so much, will give this ago!

Comment: Out of interest, if you have many UserControls loaded, how would you remove them all to get back to the main window?

Comment: I do have many UserControls. I have a MainWindow and it only has 1 child which is one grid with 10 UserControls. At most I only show 1 UserControl and I transition between them....For your case you need you would change the USerControl glabals to UIelements and you can use any UIElement (Pages, Windows, UserControl, etc.)

Comment: Just trying to get your example code running but some errors:

The type or namespace name 'TransitionEffect' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The name 'Global' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I mentioned that I modified the original library

Comment: I added my new modified code above, I'd appreciate if you could help - I still can't get the panels to appear in the correct order.

Comment: If you want to upload your project I'm sure i can help you offline